# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)) when i try to connect client .net app with OPC server

Tags: .net, opc, hresult

i have two .net apps:

1. the first allows to start OPC server
2. the second connects to the first to get data from the server.

The OPC server is saved in the register, but when i try to connect to the OPC server, an exception HRESULT is handled:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))
Any suggestions about this exception please?
Thanks alot

Comment: That is a quite general error. Do you use an OPC library? Did you double check the adres is correct?

Comment: i'm using OPCdotNETLib, address of what pls?